# Import csv into a gridview using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, csv

In my asp.net app there are two options to import a CSV file into a gridview.

One is `StreamReader` like this:

```
string rowValue;
string[] cellValue;

System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(txtPath.Text);

// Reading header
rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');                

for (int i = 0; i <= cellValue.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    column.Name = cellValue[i];
    column.HeaderText = cellValue[i];

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
}

// Reading content
while (streamReader.Peek() != -1)
{
     rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
     cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');

     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue);
}

streamReader.Close();
```

The other is using OleDb:

```
string cmdString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(target + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdString, connString);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

What's the difference between these two? Is there an advantage to using one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **StreamReader** :-

for example, my data in csv file is like this.

Copy this below data in to notepad and save as it "test.csv" and try

```
id,name,address
1,user1,India
2,user2,"Chennai,India"
```

in first row string array  you will get like this `{1,user1,India}`

But, problem with second is `{2,user2,"Chennai,India"}`

using **OleDb**:-

I feel, it is best to use OleDb. Because, we no need to worry about string manipulation.
And we access the data using SQL WHERE conditions.

Comment: using oledb here is almost the same when you read an excel file,does that mean in this approach I should install Microsoft Office in the server to read csv file

Comment: To read CSV file using oledb, we no need to install Ms Office in the machine.